# Camel combining components Timer + PollEnrich + Aggregator + ActiveMQ

Tags: xml, spring, apache-camel

I'm working on a route that at scheduled time consumes a queue and groups the messages, but the poll enrich can't take more of 1 message from the broker, I tried using the aggregator but doesn't work. This is an example code using XML Spring definitions for the camel routes:

This is the route that creates the messages:

```
    <route id="routeAmqTesting">
        <description>Route that send messages to Amq</description>
        <from uri="timer:hello?period=1s"/>
        <setBody>
            <simple>Hello World at ${date:now:hh:mm:ss}</simple>
        </setBody>
        <log message="Sending message to Amq ${body}"/>
        <to uri="activemq:queue:Q-TechnicalRetries"/>
    </route>
```

This is the route that consumes the messages:

```
    <route id="routeAmqInvoker">
        <description>Route that a sheduled time read the messages from amq</description>
        <from uri="timer:hello2?delay=10s&amp;repeatCount=1"/>
        <log message="[${camelId}] Reading messages from broker"/>
        <pollEnrich uri="activemq:queue:Q-TechnicalRetries" timeout="1000"/>
        <aggregate groupExchanges="true">
            <correlationExpression>
                <simple>true</simple>
            </correlationExpression>
            <completionTimeout>
                <constant>1000</constant>
            </completionTimeout>
            <log message="The number of exchanges is ${body.size}"/>
            <log message="Exchanges: ${body}"/>
        </aggregate>
    </route>
```

The log only shows that 1 message was aggregated, but it should show that in this case 10 messages should be aggregated.

```
[nce) thread #7 - timer://hello] timeAndAttendance              INFO  Sending message to Amq Hello World at 10:19:35
[nce) thread #7 - timer://hello] timeAndAttendance              INFO  Sending message to Amq Hello World at 10:19:36
...
[d #1 - AggregateTimeoutChecker] timeAndAttendance              INFO  The number of exchanges is 1
[d #1 - AggregateTimeoutChecker] timeAndAttendance              INFO  Exchanges: List<Exchange>(1 elements)
```

Comment: `pollEnrich only accept one message as response. That means that if you target to enrich your original message with the enricher collecting messages from a seda, ... components using an aggregation strategy. Only one response message will be aggregated with the original message.` Citation from [Content Enricher](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html)

Comment: Is there another mechanism to obtain the expected result? how i can aggregate the 10 messages after the scheduled time?